# How do I check if a radio button is clicked or not in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests

So I am trying to check if element1 radio button is clicked then if it is clicked I want to click element2 radio button, but if element2 radio button clicked then I want element1 to be clicked I tried this code and it nots showing any errors or anything but it does give the result I want

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(object.element1));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(object.element2));

if(object.element1.isSelected()){
object.element2.click();
}
if(object.element2.isSelected()){
object.element1.click();
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJmcN.png)

I tried the code I add mentioned above and it is not what the expected result was, instead it just stays the same

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here?
What is the initial state? 

case1: if by default no radio button is selected -  given the conditions you have, nothing will happen as both ifs will be false

case2: radiobutton1 is selected by default - your code will select radio button2 and the 2nd condition will be true and it will again select radiobutton1  - giving the impression of nothing has changed - try adding sleep between the 2 conditions to see if code works

case3: radiobutton2 is selected by default - you should see radiobutton1 getting clicked

Comment: Can you post the URL and the code you've tried.

Comment: By default either radio button 1 or 2 is selected, so but I want is if 1 is selected as the default selection then, according to the condition radio button 2 should be clicked, as a result radio button one will be unclicked. Ah wait why does in case 2 it will again select radiobutton1? could you please explain that? Thank you so much

Comment: Update the question with the relevant text based HTML when either of the radio button is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, if radio button 1 is selected already, then the first if condition is true, so it executes the code, result - radio button 2 is selected.
Then while checking the 2nd if condition - radio button 2 is selected now, this is also true, so this condition also executes, result - radio button 1 is selected.

So, you have to change the `if` condition:

```
if(object.element1.isSelected()){
    object.element2.click();
} else {
    object.element1.click();
}
```

Comment: ah I see, I understand now, thank you for clearing that up. so I managed to do the code this way and it works:

Comment: `
if (object.userConfiguredandEnabled.getAttribute("aria-checked").equals("true")){
             
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(object.userConfiguredbutDisabled)).click();
       Thread.sleep(2000);
}
else if(object.userConfiguredbutDisabled.getAttribute("aria-checked").equals("true")){
                
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(object.userConfiguredandEnabled)).click();    
      Thread.sleep(2000);
}
`